# One random record from everyone month

Tags: r

Say we have the following data frame:

```
    ShippedDate        OrderID  Subtotal
1   1996-07-16 00:00:00 10248   440.00
2   1996-07-10 00:00:00 10249   1863.40
...
25  1996-08-06 00:00:00 10272   1456.00
26  1996-08-12 00:00:00 10273   2142.40
...
51  1996-09-11 00:00:00 10298   3127.00
52  1996-09-13 00:00:00 10299   349.50
...
78  1996-10-14 00:00:00 10325   1497.00
79  1996-10-14 00:00:00 10326   982.00
80  1996-10-14 00:00:00 10327   2262.50
81  1996-10-17 00:00:00 10328   1168.00
etc
```

1. How to choose a record (random) for each?
   For example

```
1   1996-07-16 00:00:00 10248   440.00
2   1996-08-12 00:00:00 10273   2142.40
3   1996-09-13 00:00:00 10299   349.50
4   1996-10-14 00:00:00 10327   2262.50
```

2. how to calculate the sum for each month?
   For example

```
    1   1996-07 2303.4
    2   1996-08 3598.4
    3   1996-09 3476.5
    4   1996-10 5909.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you will create a `year-month` variable once and then use it in all the rest of the operations in order to avoid recalculating it over and over again.

Here's a possible `data.table` approach

Create variable

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, YearMonth := paste0(year(ShippedDate), "-", month(ShippedDate))]
```

Randomly sample from each year-month

```
df[, .SD[sample(seq_len(.N), 1)], by=YearMonth]
#    YearMonth         ShippedDate OrderID Subtotal
# 1:    1996-7 1996-07-16 00:00:00   10248    440.0
# 2:    1996-8 1996-08-12 00:00:00   10273   2142.4
# 3:    1996-9 1996-09-11 00:00:00   10298   3127.0
# 4:   1996-10 1996-10-14 00:00:00   10326    982.0
```

Sum per year-month

```
df[, sum(Subtotal), by=YearMonth]
#    YearMonth     V1
# 1:    1996-7 2303.4
# 2:    1996-8 3598.4
# 3:    1996-9 3476.5
# 4:   1996-10 5909.5
```

Comment: Super, thx. But how get second column form 
df[, sum(Subtotal), YearMonth]?
a <- df[,c(2)] stopped working

Comment: V1 column form df[, sum(Subtotal), YearMonth]

Comment: Oh, that's because its a `data.table` class now. You can either do `df[, "V1", with = FALSE]` or just convert it back to data.frame using `setDF(df)` and then use your syntax as normal. By the way, you can call `V1` whatever you want when aggregating, for example `df[, .(Sum = sum(Subtotal)), YearMonth]`

Comment: Also, I'd recommend looking into `data.table` vignettes as this is a great package I'd recommend you to get familiar with, see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944)

Comment: Thank you so much for everything

Answer (score 1):

You can select a random sample of size `n` (1 in your case) per month and year as (if your original data is stored as `df`):

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df_g <- group_by(df, as.character(as.yearmon(ShippedDate)))

sample_n(df_g, n, replace = FALSE)
```

You can calculate the sums per month and year as follows (using the supplied data):

```
summarise(df_g, sum = sum(Subtotal))

Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  year_mon    sum
1 Aug 1996 3598.4
2 Jul 1996 2303.4
3 Okt 1996 5909.5
4 Sep 1996 3476.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would select a random row for each month by:

```
df[tapply(1:nrow(df), substr(df$ShippedDate,1,7), FUN= sample, size= 1),]
```

To get the total of the Subtotal column for each month:

```
result <- tapply(1:nrow(df), substr(df$ShippedDate,1,7), FUN= sum)
```

If you need the "result" months and totals in a data.frame:

```
data.frame(names(result), result)
```

I really need to learn to use plyr, but for now I'm trying to learn plain R.